# Is it possible to update TextFormField using shared state (and without violating good practices)?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to make test project according to good practices.

Please note that I DON'T want any "hacky" approach. I am willing to learn good way of solving it.

My understanding of "lifting state up" is that any change updates the state, and then view is redrawn (rebuild) using current state. It is great in theory, but it DOES NOT work with TextFormField/TextEditingController.

I want to have a SharedState and bi-directonal `TextFormField`/`TextEditingController`, as follows:

case 1 (works):

TextFormField changes -> state is updated -> readonly Text (in `WidgetTwo`) is updated

case 2 (**does not work**):

button (in `WidgetOne`) is clicked -> state is updated -> TextFormField (in `WidgetThree`) shows new value from state

I have code in 3 different widgets + main file + SharedSate:

main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => sharedState(), child: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              WidgetOne(),
              WidgetTwo(),
              WidgetThree(),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

shared_state.dart

```
class SharedState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int counter = 0;

  void setCounter(int c) {
    counter = c;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrementCounter() {
    counter--;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future fetchCounterFromWeb() async {
    // simulate external call
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    setCounter(42);
  }
}
```

widget_one.dart

```
class WidgetOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var state = Provider.of<SharedState>(context, listen: false);

    return Row(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => state.decrementCounter(),
            child: Text('decrement')),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => state.incrementCounter(),
            child: Text('increment')),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => state.fetchCounterFromWeb(),
            child: Text('fetch counter from web')),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

widget_two.dart

```
class WidgetTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var state = Provider.of<SharedState>(context, listen: true);

    return Row(
      children: [Text('Value of counter is: ${state.counter}')],
    );
  }
}
```

widget_three.dart (**problem is here**)

```
class WidgetThree extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return WidgetThreeState();
  }
}

class WidgetThreeState extends State<WidgetThree> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var state = Provider.of<SharedState>(context, listen: false);
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: state.counter.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var state = Provider.of<SharedState>(context, listen: true);
    
    // THE ISSUE:
    // It is NOT possible to update Controller (or TextEditing field)
    // without this hacky line (which is not good practice)
    _controller.text = state.counter.toString();

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          onChanged: (v) {
            state.setCounter(int.parse(v.isEmpty ? '0' : v));
          },
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

I know I can possible move `TextEditingController` to `SharedState`, but SharedState should be UI agnostic, and `TextEditingController` is a UI widget.

Comment: If you look closely, you can see that `TextEditingController` is nothing more than a `ValueNotifier<T>` that extends `ChangeNotifier`.
So, it's arguable if TextEditingController should be part of UI or SharedState as its only task is to control the UI widget, not to render anything.
Same could be said for the `counter` - just because it holds the displayed value, does that mean it's also part of UI?

Comment: True, but `TextEditingController` is part of the Flutter library, while state should (?) be UI library agnostic.

Comment: If you don't want the `TextEditingController` to be part of your `SharedState`, you could add the listener right after you initialize controller in the `initState`:
`state.addListener(() => _controller.text = state.counter.toString());`
That will update the TextFormField value, and you can remove your line from the `build` method.

Comment: `state.addListener(()...` approach works. Little shame it can't be done from 'build' method which should be THE single place that rebuilds what is on the screen. Thanks!